# I get error 31 when using pcap_sendpacket with real Wi-Fi device, but it works fine with loopback

Tags: c, windows, networking, npcap

I tried compiling and running the sendpack example of the npcap sdk for C.

While running the program with a loopback interface (specifically, Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter) as an argument to pcap_sendpacket, the program works as intended, but while running the program with my real WiFi interface (TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter)  as an argument to pcap_sendpacket, the program returns an error:

`send error: PacketSendPacket failed: A device attached to the system is not functioning.  (31)`

The code I use can be downloaded here:

https://npcap.com/dist/npcap-sdk-1.13.zip

It is the sendpack.c example in Examples-pcap.

My operating system is windows 11.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the tp-link adapter (my wifi interface), restarting my pc, and reinstalling npcap.

It should also be noted that wireshark (which also uses npcap) can inspect the tp-link adapter just fine (although wireshark doesn't send packets).

Comment: Version 1.13 is quite old, as current one is 1.76, what if use up to date version?

Comment: 1.13 is the latest sdk version, I also use the latest npcap version (1.76)